# How to get pub from GitHub as a dependency

Tags: git, github, dart, dart-pub

I'm learning Dart, but I found a problem:

I want to add the [widget.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/widget.dart) package from its GitHub repository as a dependency for my project. But in pub.dartlang.org there is very old version, which requires the obsolete Web UI. Does anyone know, how to get the pub from GitHub repository (and install it like the one from the pub.dartlang.org)?

I'm using GitHub on Windows and Dart Editor.

---

**Update:** I tried to add it into a dependency and run 'pub get' in the classic way:

```
dependencies:
  widget:
    git: git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git
```

But it returns this error:

```
--- 30.1.2014 15:35:27 Running pub get ... ---
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Cannot get widget from Git (git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git).
Please ensure Git is correctly installed.
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-stable\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\source\git.dart 42  GitSource.downloadToSystemCache.<fn>
dart:isolate                                                                                         _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

This is an unexpected error. Please run

pub --trace 'get'

and include the results in a bug report on http://dartbug.com/new.

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **
```

Comment: I don't know why adding the github repository isn't an option anymore. You can clone it to you local drive (or use the download ZIP option) and use `path: ../widget` as dependency. There is not much difference between these two. 

You could clone it to your local drive and publish it yourself, but I guess the maintainer wouldn't like that much.
The last option would be to set up your own pub server and use this as dependency.

Comment: can you try if `git clone git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git` works from your command line, to check if git is properly installed.
If you don't have git and don't want to install it, you can download the zip. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly as usual - no warnings, no errors, I cloned the git repo to my local space...

Comment: pub has installation instructions for every package: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/widget#installing

Comment: Off topic Janus, but thanks for effort to help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the dependency in `pubspec.yaml` like

#### Edit pubspec.yaml in text mode

```
dependencies:
  widget:
    git: git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git
```

#### Use the assistant

if you open the `pubspec.yaml` file in DartEditor you get a nice assistant

1. click `Add...`
2. Enter name of package: 'widget'
3. Change the lookup `Source` from `hosted` to `git`
4. Set `Git ref:` to `git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git`

#### Additional Info:

- You can look up the dependency name in the file `pubspec.yaml` in the widget's GitHub repository under `name: widget`
- You can copy the git path from the GitHub repository under `SSH clone URL` (above the 'Download ZIP` button)

**EDIT**
To make this work you need to have the git command line client installed on your local system.

You can download the repository manually

```
git clone git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git
```

and add the following dependency

```
dependencies:
  widget:
    git: ../widget.dart
    # path: ../widget.dart # would work too
```

Alternatively you can download the repository from GitHub (Download as ZIP) extract it to your local drive and use a `path:` dependency like

```
dependencies:
  widget:
    path: ../widget.dart
```

provided you extracted the ZIP to a sibling folder of your package.

See also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

Comment: Well, I'm not beginner. I tried it, but still the same problem when getting pub: _--- 30.1.2014 15:26:25 Auto running pub get ... ---
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Cannot get widget from Git (git@github.com:dart-lang/widget.dart.git).
Please ensure Git is correctly installed.
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-stable\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\source\git.dart 42  GitSource.downloadToSystemCache.<fn>
dart:isolate                                                                                         _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage_

Comment: @AlesKvapil I thought I could just do a complete write-up of the topic - for anyone interested. No offence meant. 
I added the package to a playground package of mine and it was immediately downloaded and added to the package subdirectory.

Comment: I think I didn't write my question so clearly, sorry, that's my fault.

Comment: Could you describe, how to make it with git cl?

Comment: I tried your suggestion after your last edit and everything works! Thank you...

*--- 30.1.2014 15:55:24 Auto running pub get ... ---
Resolving dependencies............................................
Got dependencies!*

Comment: Do you have any idea why it made the error, when I tried it directly from the Dart Editor? Could it be a bug?

Comment: @AlesKvapil have you tried `pub --trace 'get'` and checked if it provides additional information about the failure?

Comment: Now I'm really confused: pub get/upgrade/--trace get works correctly in the command line, but not in the editor...

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't help with that.

Comment: I'll try to fix it somehow, then I'll ask a new question on Stack or fill in the bug. Thanks for you help